# Implementing Proguard Security with my APK

Tags: android, proguard

I want to configure proguard with my Application. But while doing so I am receiving the following problems :

```
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-09-24 12:27:46 - DemoProguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-09-24 12:40:50 - DemoProguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Here is my proguard-text file

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Comment: show us your proguard.cfg

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try to add these line very first on our proguard.cfg file on your project as below:

```
-ignorewarnings
```

if you have any annotation in your project so, please add the next line as below

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

and ensure your gradle file has minifyEnabled as **false**

Comment: It worked like a charm. But it has not completely Obfuscated the code. I have decompiled my apk but have seen that only some piece of code is obfuscated, and is easy to decode yet.

Comment: remove all the lines proguard.cfg add only one line -ignorewarnings and try again buddy!